# Allocate more space to Ubuntu partition

Tags: disk

I recently installed Ubuntu with dual-boot setup. I was dumb enough to just give Ubuntu 8GB with diskplace, and now it's critical.

I need more and I have a good space in my SSD. How to I extend the diskplace?

Answer (score 1):

I use this tutorial:

[How to Resize Ubuntu Root Partition](https://www.brianchristner.io/how-to-resize-ubuntu-root-partition/amp/?client=ms-android-samsung)

> **How to expand Ubuntu root filesystem**
>
> So a quick recap for those that
>   don't remember.
>
> We have to expand components of the filesystem in the
>   following order.
>
> Physical Volume -> Volume Group -> Logical Volume ->
>   Filesystem 
>   In my scenario I increased the size of my Virtual Machine
>   disk in VMware from 18GB to 28 GB.
>
> [...]